# how to set the class name based on a complex method?

Tags: angularjs

I want to set the class name of a div by calling a method as getting class name is little complex here, how can I do that?

```
<div ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <div ng-class="here i want to set class by calling method getClass(row)">...</div>
</div>
```

js code:

```
$scope.getClass = function(r) {
    if(r.id == 1)
        return "some-class";
    else if(r.id == 2)
        return "some-better-class";
    else if(r.id == 3)
        return "some-more-better-class";
    ... and so on
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just :

```
<div ng-repeat="row in rows">
  <div class="some" ng-class="getClass(row)">...</div>
</div>
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fess81/oj3xg5vb/)**</kbd>

Comment: Syntax Error: Token '(' is at column {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}].

Comment: for ng-class="{getRowClass(row)}"

Comment: @coure2011 right there is no condition. See the Demo I posted

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to style the rows based on their number, you can use angular ng-repeat '$index' property instead of a function:

```
<div ng-controller="fessCntrl">
    <div ng-repeat="row in rows">
        <div ng-class="'row'+$index">Name: {{row.name}}, Index: {{$index}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.row0 {
    background-color: red;
}
.row1 {
    background-color: blue;
}
.row2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fess81/oj3xg5vb/